# How to chain a fadeOut and restart to simple animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply drawing a line with the below in jQuery.

```
$('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({'height':'100%'},line_anim,function () {
```

I have three of these. They meet at making a triangle. I'm stumped with, however; trying to make these animations repeat 3 times / loop. Having no success creating a loop call back function - I'm wondering if I could simply chain a fadeOut with a delay. and then a restart individually, inline.

```
   var padding = $('.conn-1').css('padding');
   var line_anim = 700;
   $('.replay').hide();
   $('.conn-1').width('100%').animate({'height':'100%'},line_anim,function () {
       $('.conn-2').height('100%').animate({'width':'100%'}, line_anim,function () {
           $('.conn-3').css({width:'100%'}).animate({'height':'100%'}, line_anim, function(){
                $('.conn-1').fadeOut();
                $('.conn-1').fadeIn();
                $('.conn-2').fadeOut();
                $('.conn-2').fadeIn();
                $('.conn-3').fadeOut();
                $('.conn-3').fadeIn();
                replay();
```

Comment: Can't you just use a simple counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your starting animation function in a separate function which will start animation if it hasn't been started 3 times.

```
var started = 0;
var loop = 3;

function start_animation() {
  if (started < loop) {
    started++;

    // run animations with the last callback being start_animation
    $(element1).animate({...}, duration, function() {
      $(element1).animate({...}, duration, function() {

        // call start_animation after the last animation is complete
        $(element1).animate({...}, duration, start_animation);
      });
    });
  }
}
```